# Does "Entering a room" and "When he entered a room" have the same meaning in this context?

Tags: past-perfect, gerunds, past-simple

I know there are many similar topics but I can't still realise could I either use the following sentences in the same meaning:

1. "**Entering a room** he saw Ann where he had left her".
2. "**When he entered a room** he saw Ann where he had left her".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, but not complete same.

(1: Entering(not DONE yet)) - open the door > enter the room > you saw her.
(2: Entered(DONE)) - open > enter > close the door > turn back > you saw her.

Comment: someone said native never says the second sentence. So now, as you gave, the answer I can use both of them? The question is that they have a little different meaning? But at the same time both of them are grammatically correct?